# Convergence in distribution and convergence of expectations

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X_n)$ a sequence of complex valued random variables and $X_n \to X$ in distribution.

Portemanteau lemma stipulates that for any $f$ continuous and bounded, $\mathbf{E}\left[f(X_n)\right] \to \mathbf{E}\left[f(X)\right]$, but this doesn't include $\mathbf{E}\left[X_n\right] \to \mathbf{E}\left[X\right]$, which is not always true.

Now if we assume that $(X_n)$ are uniformly bounded by some constant $M$, does it work? It seems that by taking $f: x \in \mathbb{C} \mapsto x\mathbf{1}_{|x| \leq M} + Msign(x)\mathbf{1}_{|x| \gt M}$, then $f$ is bounded and continuous and $\mathbf{E}\left[f(X_n)\right] = \mathbf{E}\left[X_n\right]$, hence the result.

Is this proof somehow flawed? I am reading a proof which arrives at the same conclusion ($\mathbf{E}\left[X_n\right] \to \mathbf{E}\left[X\right])$ with the same boundedness assumption and using the dominated convergence theorem, but it isn't clear to me how the DCT is used with convergence in distribution.

Comment: Small problem: Your $f$ isn't continuous. But you should be able to construct a bounded continuous function $\phi:[0,\infty)\to[0,1]$ with $\phi(t)=1$ for $0\le t\le M$ and $\phi(t) = 0$ for $t\ge 2m$. Then $f(x):=x\phi(|x|)$ will do the trick.

Comment: My bad i completely forgot that my sequence is complex valued... thank you for your help. Is there anyway this can be proven using DCT?

Comment: I know what you mean by $\text{sign}(x)$, but it is probably better practice to write $x/|x|$ for $x$ complex.

Comment: In terms of your question, I am not immediately seeing how you would prove the result using the DCT, and would instead do something similar to what you (or @JohnDawkins) are doing. How does the proof you are reading go?

Comment: Probably they're using skorokhod theorem, to prove it by using DCT. Namely, there is a theorem saying, if $(X_n)$ is a sequence converging to $X$ in distribution, then there exists random variables $(Y_n)$ and $Y$, such that $Y_n \sim X_n$ and $Y \sim X$ and $Y_n \to Y$ almost surely. All that's left is to note $ 1=\mathbb P(|X_n| \le M)=\mathbb P(|Y_n| \le M)$ (due to the same distribution), so $(Y_n)$ must be uniformly bounded, too. And clearly $\mathbb E[X_n] = \mathbb E[Y_n] \to \mathbb E[Y]=\mathbb E[X]$ by DCT (with majorant $M$)

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for regarding the second part of my question !